# Weird SQLite behaviour - non-functional UPDATE SQLite method

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea, sql-update, insert-update

I am creating a Java desktop application that uses an SQLite database with over 50 data variables. I have a DatabaseHelper class that has the following  variables:

```
//-- The SQLite Database Table name --//
private static final String STAN_RECORDS_TABLE = "STAN_SQLite_Records_Table";    // Primary Table - Table 1.

//-- The STAN Records DATABASE TABLE COLUMNS - or KEYS - defined here as static variables. --//
private static final String STAN_KEY_RECORDS_ID = "Stan_Records_id";            // Record 1
private static final String STAN_KEY_DATE_CREATED = "Date_Created";             // Record 2
private static final String STAN_KEY_EST_TYPE = "Stan_Est_Type";                // Record 3
private static final String STAN_KEY_CITY_TOWN = "City_Town";                   // Record 4
private static final String STAN_KEY_LOC_LAT = "Loc_Lat";                       // Record 5
private static final String STAN_KEY_LOC_LONG = "Loc_Long";                     // Record 6
private static final String STAN_KEY_STREET_NAME = "Street_Name";               // Record 7
private static final String STAN_KEY_ERF_NUM = "Erf_Number";                    // Record 8
private static final String STAN_KEY_SUBURB_NAME = "Suburb_Name";               // Record 9
private static final String STAN_KEY_ADDRESS_DESC = "Address_Desc";             // Record 10
private static final String STAN_KEY_RATE_SINGLE = "Single_Rate";               // Record 11
private static final String STAN_KEY_RATE_DOUBLE = "Double_Rate";               // Record 12
private static final String STAN_KEY_RATE_FAMILY = "Family_Rate";               // Record 13
private static final String STAN_KEY_RATE_VIP = "VIP_Rate";                     // Record 14
private static final String STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FIXED = "Fixed_Line";             // Record 15
private static final String STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FAX = "Facsimile";                // Record 16
private static final String STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_MOBILE = "Mobile";                // Record 17
private static final String STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_EMAIL = "Email";                  // Record 18
private static final String STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_WEB = "Website";                  // Record 19
private static final String STAN_KEY_SELF_CATER = "Self_Cater";                 // Record 20
private static final String STAN_KEY_PARKING_TYPE = "Parking_Type";             // Record 21
private static final String STAN_KEY_PARKING_SHADE = "Parking_Shade";           // Record 22
private static final String STAN_KEY_PARKING_BAYS = "Parking_Bays";             // Record 23
private static final String STAN_KEY_PARKING_RATING = "Parking_Rating";         // Record 24
private static final String STAN_KEY_SINGLE_UNITS = "Single_Units";             // Record 25
private static final String STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DESC = "Single_Desc";               // Record 26
private static final String STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_UNITS = "Double_Units";             // Record 27
private static final String STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_DESC = "Double_Desc";               // Record 28
private static final String STAN_KEY_FAMILY_UNITS = "Family_Units";             // Record 29
private static final String STAN_KEY_FAMILY_DESC = "Family_Desc";               // Record 30
private static final String STAN_KEY_VIP_UNITS = "VIP_Units";                   // Record 31
private static final String STAN_KEY_VIP_DESC = "VIP_Desc";                     // Record 32
private static final String STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DOUBLE = "Single_Doubles";          // Record 33
private static final String STAN_KEY_ROOM_COND = "Room_Condition";              // Record 34
private static final String STAN_KEY_ROOM_PRIVACY = "Room_Privacy";             // Record 35
private static final String STAN_KEY_BATHROOM_SHARED = "Bathroom_Shared";       // Record 36
private static final String STAN_KEY_AIR_CON = "Air_Con";                       // Record 37
private static final String STAN_KEY_ROOM_FRIDGE = "Room_Fridge";               // Record 38
private static final String STAN_KEY_ROOM_TV = "Room_TV";                       // Record 39
private static final String STAN_KEY_ROOM_BEDDING = "Room_Bedding";             // Record 40
private static final String STAN_KEY_ROOM_SIZE = "Room_Size";                   // Record 41
private static final String STAN_KEY_BONUS_POOL = "Bonus_Pool";                 // Record 42
private static final String STAN_KEY_BONUS_GYM = "Bonus_Gym";                   // Record 43
private static final String STAN_KEY_BONUS_BAR = "Bonus_Bar";                   // Record 44
private static final String STAN_KEY_HOOD_NAME = "Hood_Name";                   // Record 45
private static final String STAN_KEY_HOOD_SAFETY = "Hood_Safety";               // Record 47
private static final String STAN_KEY_HOOD_CBD = "Hood_CBD";                     // Record 48
private static final String STAN_KEY_HOOD_NEARBY = "Hood_Nearby";               // Record 49
private static final String STAN_KEY_TOURIST_RECO = "Tourist_Reco";             // Record 50
private static final String STAN_KEY_TOURIST_REASON = "Tourist_Reason";         // Record 51
private static final String STAN_KEY_INFO_CANCEL_POLICY = "Cancel_Policy";      // Record 52
private static final String STAN_KEY_INFO_OTHER_INFO = "Other_Info";            // Record 53
private static final String STAN_KEY_EST_DB_SCORE = "Est_DB_Score";             // Record 54
private static final String STAN_KEY_DATE_UPDATED = "Date_Updated";             // Record 55
private static final String STAN_KEY_SHUTTLE_SERVICE = "Shuttle_Service";       // Record 55
private static final String STAN_KEY_KITCHEN_AVAILABLE = "Kitchen";             // Record 56
private static final String STAN_KEY_BREAKFASTS = "Breakfast";                  // Record 57
private static final String STAN_KEY_FREE_WIFI = "Free_Wifi";                   // Record 58
private static final String STAN_KEY_EST_NAME = "Est_Name";                     // Record 59
```

I then have a database creation string:

```
//-- STAN Records TABLE creation SQL Statement --//
private static final String CREATE_STAN_RECORDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + STAN_RECORDS_TABLE + " (" + /*0*/ STAN_KEY_RECORDS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + /*1*/ STAN_KEY_EST_NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," + /*2*/ STAN_KEY_EST_TYPE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*3*/ STAN_KEY_CITY_TOWN + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*4*/ STAN_KEY_DATE_CREATED + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*5*/ STAN_KEY_LOC_LAT + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*6*/ STAN_KEY_LOC_LONG + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*7*/ STAN_KEY_STREET_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*8*/ STAN_KEY_ERF_NUM + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*9*/ STAN_KEY_SUBURB_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*10*/ STAN_KEY_ADDRESS_DESC + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*11*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_SINGLE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*12*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_DOUBLE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*13*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_FAMILY + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*14*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_VIP + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*15*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FIXED + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*16*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FAX + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*17*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_MOBILE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*18*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_EMAIL + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*19*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_WEB + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*20*/ STAN_KEY_SELF_CATER + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*21*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_TYPE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*22*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_SHADE + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*23*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_BAYS + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*24*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_RATING + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*25*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_UNITS + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*26*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DESC + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*27*/ STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_UNITS + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*28*/ STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_DESC + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*29*/ STAN_KEY_FAMILY_UNITS + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*30*/ STAN_KEY_FAMILY_DESC + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*31*/ STAN_KEY_VIP_UNITS + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*32*/ STAN_KEY_VIP_DESC + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*33*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DOUBLE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*34*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_COND + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*35*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_PRIVACY + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*36*/ STAN_KEY_BATHROOM_SHARED + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*37*/ STAN_KEY_AIR_CON + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*38*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_FRIDGE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*39*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_TV + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*40*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_BEDDING + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*41*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_SIZE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*42*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_POOL + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*43*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_GYM + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*44*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_BAR + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*45*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*46*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_SAFETY + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*47*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_CBD + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*48*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_NEARBY + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*49*/ STAN_KEY_TOURIST_RECO + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*50*/ STAN_KEY_TOURIST_REASON + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*51*/ STAN_KEY_INFO_CANCEL_POLICY + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*52*/ STAN_KEY_INFO_OTHER_INFO+ " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*53*/ STAN_KEY_EST_DB_SCORE + " INTEGER, " + /*54*/ STAN_KEY_SHUTTLE_SERVICE + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*55*/ STAN_KEY_KITCHEN_AVAILABLE + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + /*56*/ STAN_KEY_BREAKFASTS + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*57*/ STAN_KEY_FREE_WIFI + " VARCHAR(255), " + /*58*/ STAN_KEY_DATE_UPDATED + " VARCHAR(255));";
```

...and a record insert string:

```
private static final String INSERT_ONE_COMPLETE_STAN_RECORDS_ENTRY = "INSERT INTO " + STAN_RECORDS_TABLE + " (" + /*1*/ STAN_KEY_EST_NAME + ", " + /*2*/ STAN_KEY_EST_TYPE + ", "
        + /*3*/ STAN_KEY_CITY_TOWN + ", " + /*4*/ STAN_KEY_DATE_CREATED + ", " + /*5*/ STAN_KEY_LOC_LAT + ", " + /*6*/ STAN_KEY_LOC_LONG + ", " + /*7*/ STAN_KEY_STREET_NAME + ", "
        + /*8*/ STAN_KEY_ERF_NUM + ", " + /*9*/ STAN_KEY_SUBURB_NAME + ", " + /*10*/ STAN_KEY_ADDRESS_DESC + ", " + /*11*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_SINGLE + ", " + /*12*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_DOUBLE + ", "
        + /*13*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_FAMILY + ", " + /*14*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_VIP + ", " + /*15*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FIXED + ", " + /*16*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FAX + ", " + /*17*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_MOBILE + ", "
        + /*18*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_EMAIL + ", " + /*19*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_WEB + ", " + /*20*/ STAN_KEY_SELF_CATER + ", " + /*21*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_TYPE + ", " + /*22*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_SHADE + ", "
        + /*23*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_BAYS + ", " + /*24*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_RATING + ", " + /*25*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_UNITS + ", " + /*26*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DESC + ", " + /*27*/ STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_UNITS + ", "
        + /*28*/ STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_DESC + ", " + /*29*/ STAN_KEY_FAMILY_UNITS + ", " + /*30*/ STAN_KEY_FAMILY_DESC + ", " + /*31*/ STAN_KEY_VIP_UNITS + ", " + /*32*/ STAN_KEY_VIP_DESC + ", "
        + /*33*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DOUBLE + ", " + /*34*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_COND + ", " + /*35*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_PRIVACY + ", " + /*36*/ STAN_KEY_BATHROOM_SHARED + ", " + /*37*/ STAN_KEY_AIR_CON + ", "
        + /*38*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_FRIDGE + ", " + /*39*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_TV + ", " + /*40*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_BEDDING + ", " + /*41*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_SIZE + ", " + /*42*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_POOL + ", "
        + /*43*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_GYM + ", " + /*44*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_BAR + ", " + /*45*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_NAME + ", " + /*46*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_SAFETY + ", " + /*47*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_CBD + ", "
        + /*48*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_NEARBY + ", " + /*49*/ STAN_KEY_TOURIST_RECO + ", " + /*50*/ STAN_KEY_TOURIST_REASON + ", " + /*51*/ STAN_KEY_INFO_CANCEL_POLICY + ", "
        + /*52*/ STAN_KEY_INFO_OTHER_INFO+ ", " + /*53*/ STAN_KEY_EST_DB_SCORE+ ", " + /*54*/ STAN_KEY_SHUTTLE_SERVICE + ", " + /*55*/ STAN_KEY_KITCHEN_AVAILABLE + ", "
        + /*56*/ STAN_KEY_BREAKFASTS + ", " + /*57*/ STAN_KEY_FREE_WIFI + ", " + /*58*/ STAN_KEY_DATE_UPDATED + ") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "
        + "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

...as well as a record UPDATE string (which is the problem!!):

```
private static final String UPDATE_ONE_COMPLETE_STAN_RECORDS_ENTRY = "UPDATE " + STAN_RECORDS_TABLE + " SET " + /*1*/ STAN_KEY_EST_NAME + " = ?, " + /*2*/ STAN_KEY_EST_TYPE + " = ?, "
        + /*3*/ STAN_KEY_CITY_TOWN + " = ?, " + /*4*/ STAN_KEY_DATE_CREATED + " = ?, " + /*5*/ STAN_KEY_LOC_LAT + " = ?, " + /*6*/ STAN_KEY_LOC_LONG + " = ?, " + /*7*/ STAN_KEY_STREET_NAME + " = ?, "
        + /*8*/ STAN_KEY_ERF_NUM + " = ?, " + /*9*/ STAN_KEY_SUBURB_NAME + " = ?, " + /*10*/ STAN_KEY_ADDRESS_DESC + " = ?, " + /*11*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_SINGLE + " = ?, " + /*12*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_DOUBLE + " = ?, "
        + /*13*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_FAMILY + " = ?, " + /*14*/ STAN_KEY_RATE_VIP + " = ?, " + /*15*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FIXED + " = ?, " + /*16*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_FAX + " = ?, " + /*17*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_MOBILE + " = ?, "
        + /*18*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_EMAIL + " = ?, " + /*19*/ STAN_KEY_CONTACTS_WEB + " = ?, " + /*20*/ STAN_KEY_SELF_CATER + " = ?, " + /*21*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_TYPE + " = ?, " + /*22*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_SHADE + " = ?, "
        + /*23*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_BAYS + " = ?, " + /*24*/ STAN_KEY_PARKING_RATING + " = ?, " + /*25*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_UNITS + " = ?, " + /*26*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DESC + " = ?, " + /*27*/ STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_UNITS + " = ?, "
        + /*28*/ STAN_KEY_DOUBLE_DESC + " = ?, " + /*29*/ STAN_KEY_FAMILY_UNITS + " = ?, " + /*30*/ STAN_KEY_FAMILY_DESC + " = ?, " + /*31*/ STAN_KEY_VIP_UNITS + " = ?, " + /*32*/ STAN_KEY_VIP_DESC + " = ?, "
        + /*33*/ STAN_KEY_SINGLE_DOUBLE + " = ?, " + /*34*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_COND + " = ?, " + /*35*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_PRIVACY + " = ?, " + /*36*/ STAN_KEY_BATHROOM_SHARED + " = ?, " + /*37*/ STAN_KEY_AIR_CON + " = ?, "
        + /*38*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_FRIDGE + " = ?, " + /*39*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_TV + " = ?, " + /*40*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_BEDDING + " = ?, " + /*41*/ STAN_KEY_ROOM_SIZE + " = ?, " + /*42*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_POOL + " = ?, "
        + /*43*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_GYM + " = ?, " + /*44*/ STAN_KEY_BONUS_BAR + " = ?, " + /*45*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_NAME + " = ?, " + /*46*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_SAFETY + " = ?, " + /*47*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_CBD + " = ?, "
        + /*48*/ STAN_KEY_HOOD_NEARBY + " = ?, " + /*49*/ STAN_KEY_TOURIST_RECO + " = ?, " + /*50*/ STAN_KEY_TOURIST_REASON + " = ?, " + /*51*/ STAN_KEY_INFO_CANCEL_POLICY + " = ?, "
        + /*52*/ STAN_KEY_INFO_OTHER_INFO+ " = ?, " + /*53*/ STAN_KEY_EST_DB_SCORE+ " = ?, " + /*54*/ STAN_KEY_SHUTTLE_SERVICE + " = ?, " + /*55*/ STAN_KEY_KITCHEN_AVAILABLE + " = ?, "
        + /*56*/ STAN_KEY_BREAKFASTS + " = ?, " + /*57*/ STAN_KEY_FREE_WIFI + " = ?, " + /*58*/ STAN_KEY_DATE_UPDATED + " = ?" + " WHERE " + STAN_KEY_RECORDS_ID + " = ?";
```

Here is my actual SQLite Update query method:

```
@Override
public void updateRecordByDatabaseId (StanRecord stanRecord, int dbID) {

    Connection stanDbCon = null;
    PreparedStatement stanDbPrepState = null;

    try {

        // [1] Make an SQL connection the STAN Records SQLite database.
        stanDbCon = StanConnectConfig.getStanConnection();

        // [2] Define the SQLite Statement to be used for inserting data into the database.
        stanDbPrepState = stanDbCon.prepareStatement(UPDATE_ONE_COMPLETE_STAN_RECORDS_ENTRY);

        // [3] Insert the passed data into the STAN Records SQLite database (one-by-one).
        stanDbPrepState.setString(1, stanRecord.getEstablishment_Name());           // Entry 1: Est_Name
        stanDbPrepState.setString(2, stanRecord.getEstablishment_Type());           // Entry 2: Est_Type
        stanDbPrepState.setString(3, stanRecord.getCity_Town());                    // Entry 3: City_Town
        stanDbPrepState.setString(4, stanRecord.getDate_Created());                 // Entry 4: Date_Created
        stanDbPrepState.setString(5, stanRecord.getLoc_Lat());                      // Entry 5: Loc_Lat
        stanDbPrepState.setString(6, stanRecord.getLoc_Long());                     // Entry 6: Loc_Long
        stanDbPrepState.setString(7, stanRecord.getPhys_Street_Name());             // Entry 7: Street_Name
        stanDbPrepState.setString(8, stanRecord.getPhys_Erf_Number());              // Entry 8: Erf_Number
        stanDbPrepState.setString(9, stanRecord.getPhys_Suburb_Name());             // Entry 9: Suburb_Name
        stanDbPrepState.setString(10, stanRecord.getPhys_Address_Desc());           // Entry 10: Address_Desc
        stanDbPrepState.setString(11, stanRecord.getRate_Single());                 // Entry 11: Rate_Single
        stanDbPrepState.setString(12, stanRecord.getRate_Double());                 // Entry 12: Rate_Double
        stanDbPrepState.setString(13, stanRecord.getRate_Family());                 // Entry 13: Rate_Family
        stanDbPrepState.setString(14, stanRecord.getRate_Vip());                    // Entry 14: Rate_VIP
        stanDbPrepState.setString(15, stanRecord.getContacts_Fixed());              // Entry 15: Contacts_Fixed
        stanDbPrepState.setString(16, stanRecord.getContacts_Fax());                // Entry 16: Contacts_Fax
        stanDbPrepState.setString(17, stanRecord.getContacts_Mobile());             // Entry 17: Contacts_Mobile
        stanDbPrepState.setString(18, stanRecord.getContacts_Email());              // Entry 18: Contacts_Email
        stanDbPrepState.setString(19, stanRecord.getContacts_Website());            // Entry 19: Contacts_Website
        stanDbPrepState.setString(20, stanRecord.getSelf_Cater());                  // Entry 20: Self_Cater
        stanDbPrepState.setString(21, stanRecord.getParking_Type());                // Entry 21: Parking_Type
        stanDbPrepState.setString(22, stanRecord.getParking_Shade());               // Entry 22: Parking_Shade
        stanDbPrepState.setString(23, stanRecord.getParking_Bays());                // Entry 23: Parking_Bays
        stanDbPrepState.setString(24, stanRecord.getParking_Rating());              // Entry 24: Parking_Rating
        stanDbPrepState.setString(25, stanRecord.getRooms_Single_Units());          // Entry 25: Single_Units
        stanDbPrepState.setString(26, stanRecord.getRooms_Single_Desc());           // Entry 26: Single_Desc
        stanDbPrepState.setString(27, stanRecord.getRooms_Double_Units());          // Entry 27: Double_Units
        stanDbPrepState.setString(28, stanRecord.getRooms_Double_Desc());           // Entry 28: Double_Desc
        stanDbPrepState.setString(29, stanRecord.getRooms_Family_Units());          // Entry 29: Family_Units
        stanDbPrepState.setString(30, stanRecord.getRooms_Family_Desc());           // Entry 30: Family_Desc
        stanDbPrepState.setString(31, stanRecord.getRooms_Vip_Units());             // Entry 31: VIP_Units
        stanDbPrepState.setString(32, stanRecord.getRooms_Vip_Desc());              // Entry 32: VIP_Desc
        stanDbPrepState.setString(33, stanRecord.getRooms_Single_Double());         // Entry 33: Single_Double
        stanDbPrepState.setString(34, stanRecord.getRooms_Overall_Condition());     // Entry 34: Overall_Condition
        stanDbPrepState.setString(35, stanRecord.getRooms_Privacy());               // Entry 35: Room_Privacy
        stanDbPrepState.setString(36, stanRecord.getRooms_Bath_Shared());           // Entry 36: Bath_Shared
        stanDbPrepState.setString(37, stanRecord.getInroom_Air_Con());              // Entry 37: Air_Con
        stanDbPrepState.setString(38, stanRecord.getInroom_Fridge());               // Entry 38: Room_Fridge
        stanDbPrepState.setString(39, stanRecord.getInroom_Tv());                   // Entry 39: Room_TV
        stanDbPrepState.setString(40, stanRecord.getInroom_Bedding());              // Entry 40: Room_Bedding
        stanDbPrepState.setString(41, stanRecord.getInroom_Space());                // Entry 41: Room_Size or Space
        stanDbPrepState.setString(42, stanRecord.getBonus_Fac_Pool());              // Entry 42: Bonus_Pool
        stanDbPrepState.setString(43, stanRecord.getBonus_Fac_Gym());               // Entry 43: Bonus_Gym
        stanDbPrepState.setString(44, stanRecord.getBonus_Fac_Bar());               // Entry 44: Bonus_inHouse Bar
        stanDbPrepState.setString(45, stanRecord.getHood_Name());                   // Entry 45: Hood_Name
        stanDbPrepState.setString(46, stanRecord.getHood_Safety());                 // Entry 46: Hood_Safety
        stanDbPrepState.setString(47, stanRecord.getHood_Dist_Cbd());               // Entry 47: Hood_CBD
        stanDbPrepState.setString(48, stanRecord.getHood_Nearby_Attractions());     // Entry 48: Hood_Other Unknown
        stanDbPrepState.setString(49, stanRecord.getTourist_Rating_Reco());         // Entry 49: Tourist_Recommendation
        stanDbPrepState.setString(50, stanRecord.getTourist_Rating_Reason());       // Entry 50: Tourist_Reason
        stanDbPrepState.setString(51, stanRecord.getInfo_Cancel_Policy());          // Entry 51: Cancel_Policy
        stanDbPrepState.setString(52, stanRecord.getInfo_Other_Info());             // Entry 52: Other_Info
        stanDbPrepState.setInt(53, stanRecord.getStan_Db_Sore());                   // Entry 53: DataBase_Score
        stanDbPrepState.setString(54, stanRecord.getStan_Fac_Shuttle());            // Entry 54: Shuttle_Service
        stanDbPrepState.setString(55, stanRecord.getStan_Fac_Kitchen());            // Entry 55: Kitchen_Availability
        stanDbPrepState.setString(56, stanRecord.getStan_Fac_Breakfast());          // Entry 56: Breakfast_Quality
        stanDbPrepState.setString(57, stanRecord.getStan_Fac_Wifi());               // Entry 57: Free_WiFi
        stanDbPrepState.setString(58, stanRecord.getDate_Updated());                // Entry 58: Date_Updated

        // [4] Identify the location point in Stan Database.
        stanDbPrepState.setInt(59, dbID);

        // [5] Execute the data insertion into the Records database.
        stanDbPrepState.executeUpdate();

        // [6] Confirm data insert with an alert to user.
        // System.out.println("\n" + UPDATE_ONE_COMPLETE_STAN_RECORDS_ENTRY);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, UPDATE_ONE_COMPLETE_STAN_RECORDS_ENTRY);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        if (stanDbPrepState != null) {

            try {

                stanDbPrepState.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (stanDbCon != null) {

            try {

                stanDbCon.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the SQLite methods (create, read, insert & delete) work well. It is just the Update method that doesn't work. It executes all the way to displaying the JOptionPane code...

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, UPDATE_ONE_COMPLETE_STAN_RECORDS_ENTRY);
```

...and even displays the message as if the data was successfully updated. But when you look at the row you wanted to update nothing was changed (still the original insert data). Please help - I have been struggling with  this code for more than a week now. Please note: I am fairly new to pure Java programming. Am using the IntelliJ IDEA IDE to develop this application. Any help will greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Shore-T!

Comment: Why set index 3 again (as in `int`)? `stanDbPrepState.setInt(3, dbID);`  It was set once before (as a `String`) `stanDbPrepState.setString(3, stanRecord.getCity_Town());`

Comment: Oh snap! How did I miss that? Late night coding... Thanks 'PathFinderElite'.  Your comment helped me. If you upload that as an answer to the question then I can select it as the correct answer and give you some points. Thanks a lot. I think I needed some new eyes to look at the code. I can't believe such a stupid mistake put me back a whole week. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index 3 is being set twice. The second time it is set, it's set as an int.

Comment: Thanks man...I really appreciate the fresh set of eyes. Two thumbs up to you!!